# creating a django model which will retain the otherwise deleted (CASCADED) model instances(Like a Watchlist)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a model called "Post", another called "Event" and finally "Watchlist". Now, each post is associated with an event. When an event is complete, that instance of the event model is deleted, and with it, the post model is CASCADED. What I want is, for the Post instance to be deleted if the Event is deleted, but retained if the Post is added to Watchlist even after the event is over:

My Models right now are:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(3, "Title must be greater than 3 characters")]
    )
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=DEFAULT_EXAM_ID)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Event(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="registered")

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name="saved")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am having trouble finding a proper way to implement the described feature.
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this in three steps:

1. Specify [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for your Watchlist's M2M field. This will allow you to:
2. Set [`models.PROTECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) to the `on_delete` for the post.

Should look something like this:

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name="saved", through='Watch')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Watch(models.Model):
    watchlist = models.ForeignKey(Watchlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

3. Handle the `ProtectedError` exception in wherever you invoke the deletion from.

Answer (score 1):

I would set `on_delete` to `models.DO_NOTHING` in each of your models and do the logic in `delete` method of corresponding models, e.g.:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=DEFAULT_EXAM_ID)
    # ...

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        if self.saved.exists():
            return
        super().delete(using, keep_parents)


class Event(models.Model):
    # ...

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        posts = self.post_set.all()
        for post in posts:
            post.delete()
        super().delete(using, keep_parents)
```